# Procedure or function 'ACMS_add' expects parameter '@ACMS_doc_nane', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net

I'm getting this error, can you help me? thanks in advance

> Procedure or function 'ACMS_add' expects parameter '@ACMS_doc_name', which was not supplied.

Class

```
public bool ACMS_add( string ENTRYUSER)
{
    bool status = false;
    ACMS_core.settings.ACMS_global_settings Conn = new ACMS_core.settings.ACMS_global_settings();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conn.myConnectionString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ACMS_add", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_Number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ACMS_Number;
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ACMS_Date;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_Type", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ACMS_Type;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@enrty_user", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ENTRYUSER;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_doc_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ACMS_doc_name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_doc_file", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ACMS_doc_file;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_doc_ext", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ACMS_doc_ext;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_doc_mime_type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ACMS_doc_mime_type;

    conn.Open();

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        status = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // return ex.Message;
        status = false;
    }

    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();

    return status;
}
```

Procedure

```
            USE [TaxDisputes]
        GO
        /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ACMS_add]    Script Date: 1/11/2013 5:04:01 PM ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        -- =============================================
        -- Author:      <Author,,Name>
        -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
        -- =============================================
        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ACMS_add]


        @ACMS_Number as nvarchar (50),
        --@ACMS_Date as datetime,
        @ACMS_Type as int,
        @enrty_user as nvarchar (50),
        @ACMS_doc_name  nvarchar (250),         
        @ACMS_doc_file image ,
        @ACMS_doc_ext nvarchar(50),
        @ACMS_doc_mime_type varchar(250)

        AS
        BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        ----#
        DECLARE @doc_type int

        IF exists (select mimetype from dbo.itdc_doc_extenstions where mimetype = @ACMS_doc_mime_type)
        BEGIN

        SET @doc_type = (select doc_ext_id from dbo.itdc_doc_extenstions where mimetype = @ACMS_doc_mime_type)

        END
        ELSE

        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[itdc_doc_extenstions]
                        (
                        [doc_ext],
                        [mimetype]
                        )
        VALUES
                        (
                        @ACMS_doc_ext,  
                        @ACMS_doc_mime_type                     
                        )   
        SET @doc_type = @@IDENTITY          

        END

        ----#
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[itdc_ACMS]
        (
        [ACMS_Number]
        -- ,[ACMS_Date]
        ,[ACMS_Type]
        ,[entry_user]
        ,[ACMS_doc_name]
        ,[ACMS_doc_file]
        )
        VALUES

        (
        @ACMS_Number,
        -- @ACMS_Date,
        @ACMS_Type,
        @enrty_user,
        @ACMS_doc_name, 
        @ACMS_doc_file
        )

        END
        END
```

Codebehind

```
protected void Submitform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    itdc_core.db_ACMS.acms acmsAdd = new acms();
    String fileName = DocUpload.FileName;

    if (fileName != "")
    {
        String file_ext = "";

        try
        {
            file_ext = fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("."), fileName.Length - fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
        }
        catch
        {
            file_ext = "";
        }

        try
        {
            acmsAdd.ACMS_Number = docNumber.Text.Trim();
            //acmsAdd.ACMS_Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-01-10 19:08:12.300");
            acmsAdd.ACMS_Type = Convert.ToInt32(docType.SelectedValue);
            acmsAdd.ACMS_add(Page.User.Identity.Name);
            acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_name = DocUpload.FileName.ToString();
            acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_file = DocUpload.FileBytes;
            acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_mime_type = DocUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
            acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_ext = file_ext;

            litDeleteDocumentMessage.Text = ("File added succsesfully");
        }
        catch
        {
            litDeleteDocumentMessage.Text = "Error !!! try again later";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        litDeleteDocumentMessage.Text = "Please choose  document !!! ";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but have you tried [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: In this line: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACMS_doc_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ACMS_doc_name;` Have you checked what is value of `ACMS_doc_name`? Never used such Add syntax and not sure how it works, but maybe you have a null there or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call your method after you have initialized all properties:

```
acmsAdd.ACMS_Number = docNumber.Text.Trim();
//acmsAdd.ACMS_Date = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-01-10 19:08:12.300");
acmsAdd.ACMS_Type = Convert.ToInt32(docType.SelectedValue);
acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_name = DocUpload.FileName.ToString();
acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_file = DocUpload.FileBytes;
acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_mime_type = DocUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;
acmsAdd.ACMS_doc_ext = file_ext;
```

and last (since that's executing the stored-procedure):

```
acmsAdd.ACMS_add(Page.User.Identity.Name);
```

A better way would be to change the signature of the method so that all parameters must be provided.

Answer (score 2):

In your procedure code you have the following.....

```
@ACMS_Number as nvarchar (50),
--@ACMS_Date as datetime,
@ACMS_Type as int,
@enrty_user as nvarchar (50),
@ACMS_doc_name  nvarchar (250),         
@ACMS_doc_file image ,
@ACMS_doc_ext nvarchar(50),
@ACMS_doc_mime_type varchar(250)
```

Now I'm not a user of C# but i notice that your doc_file_name AND some other lines do not have an "AS" clause in them...

Do you think maybe this could be the issue?

Comment: Not that you'd need to be a user of C# to know anything about this. More SQL, I'd say. ;)

Comment: `AS` for aliasing is optional :)